# relationships in rest?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, rest

I want to add a person to a community and im not sure how its done?

My datacontract looks like this:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Community")]
public class Community
{

    public Group() 
    {
        People = new List<Person>();
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "CommunityName")]
    public string CommunityName { get; set; }
    public List<Person> People { get; set; }

}
[DataContract(Name = "Person")]
public class Person
{
    [DataMember(Name = "PersonName")]
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
}
```

In my service I can add a person or a community like so:

```
List<Community> Communitys = new List<Community>();
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
public void AddCommunity(Community community)
{
     Communitys.Add(community);
}
public void AddPerson(Person person)
{
     people.Add(person); 
}

public void AddPersonToCommunity(Person person, Community community)
{
    //not sure what to do here
}
```

But I am unsure how to join a person to a community

```
public void AddPersonToCommunity(Person person, Community community)
{
    //community.CommunityName(Person.Add);?
}
```

And I have a windows form which when I POST either a person or a community it is done like so:

```
{
    StringBuilder Community = new StringBuilder();
    Community.AppendLine("<Community>");
    Community.AppendLine("<CommunityName>" + this.textBox4.Text + "</CommunityName>");
    Community.AppendLine("</Community>");
```

But How would you (once completed) take the AddPersonToCommunity and make a string builder in order to add a person to a community?

```
    {
        StringBuilder CommunityAddPerson = new StringBuilder();
        CommunityAddPerson.AppendLine("<Community&{1}>");
        CommunityAddPerson.AppendLine ......
        CommunityAddPerson.AppendLine("<CommunityName>" + this.textBox4.Text + "</CommunityName>");
        CommunityAddPerson.AppendLine("</Community>");
```

Hope this is more clear its two questions in one I guess.

Comment: Don't you think you need an `AddPersonToCommunity(Community community, Person person)` method in order to accomplish what you are saying?

Comment: Yes Bryan but what do I put in the method?

Comment: Your questions and thoughts are all over the place.  Please re-phrase your question and be more coherent.  It's unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your method, based on what you are saying, might look like this:

```
public void AddPersonToCommunity(string person, string communityName)
{
    var result = communities.Where(n => String.Equals(n.CommunityName, communityName)).FirstOrDefault();
    if (result != null)
    {
        result.Add(new Person() { Name = person });
    }
}
```

Your POST data may look like this:

```
<Community>
  <CommunityName>CrazyTown</CommunityName>
  <People>
     <Person>Moe Howard</Person>
  </People>
</Community>
```

Comment: @KirstyWhite: Are you referring to LINQ?

Comment: @KirstyWhite: You can start here on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx

Comment: @KirstyWhite: You might want to go back to some C# basics if that is the case.  I don't want to create a discussion here.  If it's something you are stuck on, please post another question here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You could always add a method to add a person to a community:

```
public void AddPersonToCommunity(Person person, Community community)...
```

or

```
public void AddPersonToCommunity(string personName, string communityName)...
```