# No definition for add in linq syntax?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, rest

I was getting help related to a previous question but then told to ask a new question related to it but the code given I run into an error:

```
public void AddPersonToCommunity(string person, string communityName) 
{ 
    var result = communities.Where(n => String.Equals(n.CommunityName, communityName)).FirstOrDefault(); 
    if (result != null) 
    { 
        result.Add(new Person() { PersonName = person }); //no definition for add?
    } 
}
```

You can see the previous question here for more specifics: [relationships in rest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046196/relationships-in-rest)

If I do `var result = communities;` result will then have the definition for Add so im not sure whats going on?

Comment: This would work if instead of firstordefault you used tolist so that result is a collection and not a single entity. Though what are you going for with the add--insert in to the database?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're calling `Where()` which will return an `IEnumerable<Community>` (no `Add` method) and then `FirstOrDefault()` which returns a `Community` (also no `Add` method). Where would you *expect* an `Add` method to come from?

I suspect you *really* want:

```
if (result != null) 
{ 
    result.People.Add(new Person { PersonName = person });
}
```

... because `Community.People` is a list of the people in that community, right?

Note that if you do `var result = communities;` there will indeed be an Add method - but with a signature of `Add(Community)`, *not* `Add(Person)`.

It's important that you keep the types of everything straight. This actually has very little to do with LINQ. You'd have seen the same result if you'd tried:

```
Community community = new Community();
community.Add(new Person { PersonName = person });
```

Comment: Thanks Jon will try in a minute

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto @Jon's answer

There is a `Concat` extension method for `IEnumerable<T>` which allows you to logically combine two `IEnumerable<T>` objects into a single `IEnumerable<T>` which spans both collection.  You could extend this logic to appending a single element and then apply that to your current situation.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Concat(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, T value) {
  foreach (var cur in enumerable) {
    yield return cur;
  }
  yield return value;
}

...

result = result.Concat(new Person() { PersonName = person });
```